# Blender pauses during render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

When rendering, Blender usually is frozen until the image is rendered.

However for my scene, Blender is 100% responsive, and renders significantly slower.

For reference, viewport render works fine as expected.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: please give us much more details - big scene? eevee? cycles? statistics? or provide your blend file

Answer (score 2):

in the render tab, theres this option, lock interface:

[image]

as the description says, it locks your blender when rendering to give more memory
its locked as a default, maybe you accidentaly unchecked it

Comment: Good suggestion! Sadly doesn't solve it though.